# FileUploader accept="image/*" validation problem

Tags: html, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-javascript

I added `accept="image/*"` attribute to file uploader `<input type="file" name="imageUploader">`.

I select any image file in uploader. And try to send data to server. But imageUploader set error and add `class="input-validation-error"`.

Why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

you should try specifying the type in the php for the imageuploader and if you still have problems, add each image type seperately e.g.

```
== "image/jpeg" or "image/png" or "image/gif"
```